# How to display the content of a TextArea from the HtmlDocument of a WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a TextArea in a page of my Site, I want to display the text of this TextArea, using the Document of a WebBrowser Control, to a Label.

This is the TextArea definition:

```
<textarea class="cadr" id="bar" name="saisie"style="height: 260px; width: 700px;"> simple text</textarea>
```

How can I do it? I have this code:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(label1.text).GetAttribute("value", "bar")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element you describe has no ID, so you have to resort to the `className` of both the `TEXTAREA` and its `DIV` parent (to narrow down the chance to get the wrong element).

```
<div class="labelapper"><textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="Label">text1</textarea></div>
```

You can use `GetElementsByTagName()` instead of `GetElementsById()`, then filter the results

Something like this:

```
Imports System.Linq
' [...]

dim innerText = String.Empty
dim textArea = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA").
    OfType(Of HtmlElement)().
    FirstOrDefault(Function(elm) elm.GetAttribute("className") = "Label" AndAlso 
        elm.Parent.GetAttribute("className") = "labelapper")
if textArea IsNot Nothing Then
    innerText = textArea.InnerText
End If
```

EDIT: The HtmlElement in the original post has been changed, now showing an ID

```
dim textArea = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("bar")
if textArea IsNot Nothing Then
    label1.Text = textArea.InnerText
End If
```

Comment: Where is write the lable1.text     there is no label showing

Comment: Why did you change the HTML of the TextArea element in the question? Was it the wrong element definition? The code I posted is related to the TextArea definition you originally posted. Does it have an ID now? Are you going to change the HTML another time or is it going to stay as it is now?

Comment: Dear now i have post the real textarea please update your code now i want show textarea text in label ......

Comment: Right. So, do you want to retrive the TextArea content and show in in `label1.text`? Because, now, you have `.GetElementById(label1.text)`, which implies that the ID of the HtmlElement is taken from a Label, not that the Label is set with the text of the element

Comment: i want to show my textarea text in label please update the code ...